# Attempting to add QLayout "" to convertidorNumericoDialogo "" which already has a layout

Tags: c++, qt

what's up friends,  I got the issue of the title, programm working with 3 QLineEdit where 1st it's to introduce a decimal number, 2nd a hex,  and the 3rd a binary.

I got signals that works while I introduce a decimal number then it puts the hex value in the 2nd QLineEdit(it's converted by signal) , and to the same way for the binary value.

until here, before was working(but not now), after I put a code to  introduce a binary or hex, then it becomes to decimal , and the other val...

I need your help, maybe I'm not seeing something .... it's literally the first time I used QGidLayout, etc etc.

#### my code is next:

### code of convertidorNumerico.cpp

```c
#include "convertidornumerico.h"

convertidorNumerico::convertidorNumerico(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void convertidorNumerico::setDec(const QString &cadena)
{
    bool ok;
    int num = cadena.toInt(&ok);
    if ( ok )
    {
        emit hexChanged(QString::number(num, 16));
        emit binChanged(QString::number(num, 2));
    }
    else
    {
        emit hexChanged("");
        emit binChanged("");
    }
}

void convertidorNumerico::setHex(const QString &cadena)
{
    bool ok;
    int num = cadena.toInt(&ok, 16);
    if ( ok )
    {
        emit decChanged(QString::number(num));
        emit binChanged(QString::number(num, 2));
    }
    else
    {
        emit decChanged("");
        emit binChanged("");
    }
}

void convertidorNumerico::setBin(const QString &cadena)
{
    bool ok;
    int num = cadena.toInt(&ok);
    if ( ok )
    {
        emit decChanged(QString::number(num));
        emit hexChanged(QString::number(num, 16));
    }
    else
    {
        emit decChanged("");
        emit hexChanged("");
    }
}
```

### code of convertidorNumerico.h

```c
#ifndef CONVERTIDORNUMERICO_H
#define CONVERTIDORNUMERICO_H

#include <QObject>

class convertidorNumerico : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit convertidorNumerico( QObject *parent = nullptr );

signals:
    void decChanged(const QString &);
    void hexChanged(const QString &);
    void binChanged(const QString &);

public slots:
    void setDec(const QString &);
    void setHex(const QString &);
    void setBin(const QString &);
};

#endif // CONVERTIDORNUMERICO_H
```

### code of convertidorNumericoDialogo.cpp

```c
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QIntValidator>
#include <QRegularExpression>
#include <QRegularExpressionValidator>

#include "convertidornumericodialogo.h"
#include "convertidornumerico.h"

/*convertidorNumericoDialogo::convertidorNumericoDialogo(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}*/

convertidorNumericoDialogo::convertidorNumericoDialogo()
{
    QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout   ( this );
    QGridLayout *editLayout = new QGridLayout   ( this );
    QHBoxLayout *btnLayout = new QHBoxLayout    ( this );

    QLabel *decLabel = new QLabel("decimal");
    QLabel *hexLabel = new QLabel("Hexadecimal");
    QLabel *binLabel = new QLabel("Binario");

    decEdit = new QLineEdit;
    hexEdit = new QLineEdit;
    binEdit = new QLineEdit;

    editLayout->addWidget(decLabel, 0, 0);
    editLayout->addWidget( decEdit, 0, 1 );
    editLayout->addWidget( hexLabel, 1, 0 );
    editLayout->addWidget( hexEdit, 1, 1 );

    editLayout->addWidget(binLabel, 2, 0);
    editLayout->addWidget(binEdit, 2, 1);

    QPushButton *btnSalir = new QPushButton("SALIR");
    btnLayout->addStretch();
    btnLayout->addWidget(btnSalir);

    mainLayout->addLayout(editLayout);
    mainLayout->addStretch();
    mainLayout->addLayout(btnLayout);

    btnSalir->setDefault(true);
    connect(btnSalir, SIGNAL(released()), this, SLOT(accept()));

    // VALORES DE UN BYTE : 0 - 255
    QIntValidator *decVal = new QIntValidator(0, 255, decEdit);
    decEdit->setValidator(decVal);

    // EXP REG PARA VALIDAR HEXADECIMALES DE HASTA 2 DIGITOS....
    QRegularExpressionValidator *hexVal = new QRegularExpressionValidator(
                QRegularExpression("^[0-9A-Fa-f]{1,2}"), hexEdit);
    hexEdit->setValidator(hexVal);

    // EXP REG PARA VALIDAR BINARIOS DE HASTA 8 BYTES....
    QRegularExpressionValidator *binVal = new QRegularExpressionValidator(
                QRegularExpression("[0-1]{1,8}"), binEdit);
    binEdit->setValidator(binVal);

    convertidorNumerico *convertidor = new convertidorNumerico;

    connect(decEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), convertidor, SLOT(setDec(QString)));
    connect(convertidor, SIGNAL(hexChanged(QString)), hexEdit, SLOT(setText(QString)));
    connect(convertidor, SIGNAL(binChanged(QString)), binEdit, SLOT(setText(QString)));


    // tarea: => CONECTAR las señales de hexa y binario, para que ingresando esos datos, se devuelva la info en la app.
    connect(hexEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), convertidor, SLOT(setHex(QString)));
    connect(binEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged(QString)), convertidor, SLOT(setBin(QString)));
    connect(convertidor, SIGNAL(decChanged(QString)), decEdit, SLOT(setText(QString)));
}
```

### code of convertidorNumericoDialogo.h

```c
#ifndef CONVERTIDORNUMERICODIALOGO_H
#define CONVERTIDORNUMERICODIALOGO_H

#include <QDialog>


class QLineEdit;
class convertidorNumericoDialogo : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    //explicit convertidorNumericoDialogo(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    explicit convertidorNumericoDialogo();

private:
    QLineEdit *decEdit;
    QLineEdit *hexEdit;
    QLineEdit *binEdit;

};

#endif // CONVERTIDORNUMERICODIALOGO_H
```

any solution? I did everything and I didn't make it working...

Comment: I need to add that programm it's working( midly ), because when I introduce a value in any  QLineEdit then puts random values which I didn't put in the QLineEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting multiple layouts, change this:

```
QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout   ( this );
QGridLayout *editLayout = new QGridLayout   ( this );
QHBoxLayout *btnLayout = new QHBoxLayout    ( this );
```

to

```
QVBoxLayout *mainLayout = new QVBoxLayout   ( this );
QGridLayout *editLayout = new QGridLayout;
QHBoxLayout *btnLayout = new QHBoxLayout;
```

See https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlayout.html#QLayout

Comment: message has solve, but the function of the app is not.... When I am putting a value onto QLineEdit it puts a random value that I didn't put ... for example, I want to put 43 in QLineEdit for decimal , but it puts 11013782 and I didn't put it...

Comment: Hi. This question was about the layout issue. What you describe is a separate problem and should be posted as a separate question.